# Parsing fuction parses file but only partially

Tags: c, string, file, parsing

I'm working with a file format that I have to parse in C which looks like this:

> 5   
> 3   
> 1 3 
> 1 4 
> 1 5 
> 3   
> 2 3 
> 2 4 
> 2 5 
> 2   
> 3 1 
> 3 2 
> 3   
> 4 1 
> 4 2 
> 4 5 
> 3   
> 5 1 
> 5 2 
> 5 4

Apart from the first line, which tells us the amount of vertices, each line with one number indicates how many lines with 2 numbers follow. on these 2 number lines we can see 2 vertex ID's which are connected in a graph. My goal is to take this information and turn int into a graph. I've written the following function to read a single vertex:

```
graph_vertex_t* read_vertex(FILE *fp, graph_vertex_t *last_vertex) 
{
    graph_vertex_t *current_vertex;
    
    graph_edge_t *tmp_edge;
    
    graph_edge_t *last_edge;
    
    char *token;
    
    boolean_t error = false;
    
    current_vertex = (graph_vertex_t *)malloc(sizeof(graph_vertex_t));
    
    int tmp_number_edges = 1;
    /*Temporary character string used to read line in file. */
    char *tmp;
    /*Allocating memory for string. Again I'm assuming 64 charcters is*/
    /*all I need. */
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
    while (fgets(tmp, 
                 63, 
                 fp) != NULL 
                 &&
                 tmp_number_edges > 0)
    {   
        tmp[strcspn(tmp, "\n")] = 0;
        /* Check if the line contains a vertex number. */
        if (is_number(tmp))
        {
            /* Set the line to the vertex number. */
            tmp_number_edges = atoi(tmp);
        }
        else
        {           
            /* check if line has the right format. */
            token = strtok(tmp, " \t");
            if (is_number(token))
            {
                /* Set the identifier of the vertex. */
                current_vertex->identifier = atoi(token);
                current_vertex->next_vertex_p = last_vertex;
            }
            else
            {
                error = true;
            }
            
            token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
            if (is_number(token))
            {
                /* Make new edge. */
                tmp_edge = (graph_edge_t *)malloc(sizeof(graph_edge_t));
                tmp_edge->adjac_vertex_p = (graph_vertex_t *)malloc(sizeof(graph_vertex_t));
                tmp_edge->adjac_vertex_p->identifier = atoi(token);
                tmp_edge->next_edge_p = last_edge;              
                last_edge = tmp_edge;
                printf(" %d", tmp_edge->adjac_vertex_p->identifier);
            }
            else
            {
                error = true;
            }
            tmp_number_edges--;
        }
    }
    current_vertex->edge_list_p = tmp_edge;
    if(error)
    {
        current_vertex = NULL;
    }
    return(current_vertex);
}
```

This function is being called in a for loop which loops for the number of vertices. Then some information is printed:

```
printf("connecting to: ");
            
current_vertex = read_vertex(fp,
                             last_vertex);
printf(" found vertex ID: %d \n", current_vertex->identifier);
```

I therefor expect an output that looks somewhat like this:

> connecting to:  3 4 5 found vertex ID: 1 
> connecting to:  3 4 5 found vertex ID: 2 
> connecting to:  1 2 found vertex ID: 3   
> connecting to:  1 2 5 found vertex ID: 4 
> connecting to:  1 2 4 found vertex ID: 5

But actually it looks like this:

> connecting to:  3 4 5 found vertex ID: 1 
> connecting to:  3 found vertex ID: 2     
> connecting to:  5 found vertex ID: 2     
> connecting to:  1 found vertex ID: 3     
> connecting to:  1 2 5 found vertex ID: 4 
> connecting to:  1 found vertex ID: 5

We can see that for ID 1 and 4 the output is correct, but for the rest it isn't. What is causing this behavior? how could I fix this?

EDIT:

Here are the definitions of `graph_vertex_t` and `graph_edge_t`.

```
* Structure used to hold a graph vertex information. */
typedef struct graph_vertex
{
    int identifier;
    struct graph_vertex *next_vertex_p;
    struct graph_edge *edge_list_p;
    boolean_t visited;
} graph_vertex_t;

/* Structure used to hold a graph edge information. */
typedef struct graph_edge
{
    struct graph_vertex *adjac_vertex_p;
    struct graph_edge *next_edge_p;
} graph_edge_t;
```

Comment: Your graph has 5 vertices, but you allocate far more than that. When you read `3 1`, you cannot allocate vertex 1 right away, you already have that vertex created. You want to write an edge creation routine that allocates a vertex *if and only if there isn't a vertex with that ID already in the graph*.

Comment: In addition, your parsing is overly complicated. atoi, tokens... a single call to `sscanf` is enough.

Comment: in each sub group the first id is always the same, is it a rule or just random ? else I cannot understand the reason of the sub groups. I suppose also "3 1" is redundant after "1 3"

Comment: are `graph_vertex_t` and `graph_edge_t` defined by you ? Are the vertex ID always consecutive numbers starting at 1 ?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I'll see if I can change it to a sscanf function but I want to be able to report different errors too.

Comment: @BRHSM to check file content each time read a line then extract 1 or 2 numbers using *sscanf* check return value

Comment: @bruno The first number is the ID of the graph where the second is the graph it connects to. This means that this format will always be like that! I did indeed also define  both those structures and I'll include them in an edit!

Comment: @bruno I'll try that first then I'll let you know what I found

Comment: @BRHSM in that case simplify your life, place the vertex in a dynamically allocated array (using `realloc`to increase its size when needed) where the index is the ID-1, through a pointer or add a field saying the vertex is defined or not in the current entry

Comment: @bruno I'll try that but I first need to understand sscanf. I looked at the documentation and I think something like this 'sscanf(tmp, "%d %d", &id_orig, &id_conn)' should give me the numbers from a line that has 2 numbers with a space in between. I'm not getting those numbers tho so I don't know what's going in here... Does the string need to follow the exact format?

Comment: This sscanf call [should work](https://ideone.com/ODXWnQ). If it doesn't use the debugger to see if `tmp` has what you think it does,

Comment: It would be eaiser to use `strtol` instead of `atoi` and `strtok`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I currently have something like this to test between a string with one or 2 numbers: https://ideone.com/ecstFK however it always sais it's 2 numbers even if it's only one... how can I fix this then?

Comment: @BRHSM I put a pseudo answer only speaking about the way to read, with a level of check increasing from the first to the last

Comment: `sscanf` returns the number of items successfully scanned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your remark

> I first need to understand sscanf

to help you to read here are few proposals, out of any memorization in your structs

A first proposal without checking the numbers are or not on separated lines :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int nVertices, verticesRank;
  
  if ((scanf("%d", &nVertices) != 1) ||
      (nVertices < 0)) {
    fputs("wrong number of vertices\n", stderr);
    return -1;
  }

  for (verticesRank = 0; verticesRank < nVertices; verticesRank += 1) {
    int nGroups, groupRank, vertex;
    
    if ((scanf("%d", &nGroups) != 1) ||
        (nGroups < 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "wrong number of groups in vertices #%d\n", verticesRank);
      return -1;
    }
    
    for (groupRank = 0; groupRank < nGroups; groupRank += 1) {
      int a, b;
      
      if ((scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != 2) ||
          (a < 1) || (b < 1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong vertex IDs group #%d vertices #%d\n",
               groupRank, verticesRank);
        return -1;
      }
      
      if (groupRank == 0) {
        vertex = a;
        printf("vertex %d connecting", a);
      }
      else if (a != vertex) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong vertex ID group #%d vertices #%d, %d rather than %d\n",
                groupRank, verticesRank, a, vertex);
        return -1;
      }
      printf(" %d", b);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat > v
5
3
1 3
1 4
1 5
3
2 3
2 4
2 5
2
3 1
3 2
3
4 1
4 2
4 5
3
5 1
5 2
5 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out <v
vertex 1 connecting 3 4 5
vertex 2 connecting 3 4 5
vertex 3 connecting 1 2
vertex 4 connecting 1 2 5
vertex 5 connecting 1 2 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

A second version checking there are the right number of values per line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char line[64];
  int nVertices, verticesRank;
  int dummy;
  
  if ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) ||
      (sscanf(line, "%d%d", &nVertices, &dummy) != 1) ||
      (nVertices < 0)) {
    fputs("wrong number of vertices\n", stderr);
    return -1;
  }

  for (verticesRank = 0; verticesRank < nVertices; verticesRank += 1) {
    int nGroups, groupRank, vertex;
    
    if ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) ||
        (sscanf(line, "%d%d", &nGroups, &dummy) != 1) ||
        (nGroups < 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "wrong number of groups in vertices #%d\n", verticesRank);
      return -1;
    }
    
    for (groupRank = 0; groupRank < nGroups; groupRank += 1) {
      int a, b;
      
      if ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) ||
          (sscanf(line, "%d%d%d", &a, &b, &dummy) != 2) ||
          (a < 1) || (b < 1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong vertex IDs group #%d vertices #%d\n",
               groupRank, verticesRank);
        return -1;
      }
      
      if (groupRank == 0) {
        vertex = a;
        printf("vertex %d connecting", a);
      }
      else if (a != vertex) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong vertex ID group #%d vertices #%d, %d rather than %d\n",
                groupRank, verticesRank, a, vertex);
        return -1;
      }
      printf(" %d", b);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall cc.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out <v
vertex 1 connecting 3 4 5
vertex 2 connecting 3 4 5
vertex 3 connecting 1 2
vertex 4 connecting 1 2 5
vertex 5 connecting 1 2 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

note I do not check if there is something else than a number, so the first line is considered right being `5aze` for instance, if you need to check :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char line[64];
  int nVertices, verticesRank;
  char dummy;
  
  if ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) ||
      (sscanf(line, "%d%c", &nVertices, &dummy) != 2) ||
      (nVertices < 0) ||
      (dummy != '\n')) {
    fputs("wrong number of vertices\n", stderr);
    return -1;
  }

  for (verticesRank = 0; verticesRank < nVertices; verticesRank += 1) {
    int nGroups, groupRank, vertex;
    
    if ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) ||
        (sscanf(line, "%d%c", &nGroups, &dummy) != 2) ||
        (nGroups < 0) ||
        (dummy != '\n')) {
      fprintf(stderr, "wrong number of groups in vertices #%d\n", verticesRank);
      return -1;
    }
    
    for (groupRank = 0; groupRank < nGroups; groupRank += 1) {
      int a, b;
      
      if ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) ||
          (sscanf(line, "%d%d%c", &a, &b, &dummy) != 3) ||
          (a < 1) || (b < 1) ||
          (dummy != '\n')) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong vertex IDs group #%d vertices #%d\n",
               groupRank, verticesRank);
        return -1;
      }
      
      if (groupRank == 0) {
        vertex = a;
        printf("vertex %d connecting", a);
      }
      else if (a != vertex) {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong vertex ID group #%d vertices #%d, %d rather than %d\n",
                groupRank, verticesRank, a, vertex);
        return -1;
      }
      printf(" %d", b);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall cc.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out <v
vertex 1 connecting 3 4 5
vertex 2 connecting 3 4 5
vertex 3 connecting 1 2
vertex 4 connecting 1 2 5
vertex 5 connecting 1 2 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Notice even an extra space (out of newline) after the last expected number is considered to be an error in that case, and the last line must also finishes by a newline.

That does not check there is something after the theoretical end, you can do in several ways.

Also in your example the vertex ID being the first number in each couples are the consecutive numbers 1, 2 ..., in the proposals before I do not check that even it is easy to check `vertex == verticesRank+1`. If this is a rule why to give the couple of values for nothing when only the second number is enough ?